# Python - structure of application

Tags: python, import, directory-structure

Morning,

Got a python app I have been working on.

Currently it consits of just a couple of files but as it gets bigger I am creating more and more files and the top of my main python file I am doing

```
import url_thread
import task_database
import xxxx
import yyyy
```

and I am going to be adding another class today which is another import!

Is there a way to stick these py files into a folder, and just do import classes/*

Is there a better way I should be doing this?

More, pythonic?

Comment: You know you can do several imports on a line? i.e. `import url_thread, task_database, xxxx, yyyy` But in general, see what people are saying below about making packages and importing tidily. Avoid using `from ... import *` unless it's really necessary.

Comment: Also, you can have more than one class per module!  Just in case you're not aware.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do what you are asking, but it is not advised.

you can create a [package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) containing all your modules and then pollute your namespace by just importing everything:

```
from foo import *
```

... or a better way would be to create a nicely structured package of modules and then explicitly import them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a package and import from that package: `from mypackage import *`.

Comment: Note: That will load `__init__` and import from there. Also, be advised that `import *` has [quite a few pitfalls and therefore "considered harmful" in most cases](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import).

Answer (score 0):

Don't listen all the stuff people say about "namespace pollution". Go ahead and do `from classes import *`, if it's convenient for you (and I believe it is), but consider using [`__all__`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) in your package.

To be exact, the following folder structure would do it:

```
classes/
|-- class1.py
|-- class2.py
`-- __init__.py
```

Adding the file `classes/__init__.py` creates the package. It looks like this:

```
from class1 import Class1
from class2 import Class2

__all__ = ["Class1", "Class2"]
```

Please note the quotes around class names in `__all__`.

Then, you can use the package in whatever scripts you have:

```
>>> from classes import *
>>> Class1
<class classes.class1.Class1 at 0xb781c68c>
>>> Class2
<class classes.class2.Class2 at 0xb781c6ec>
>>> dir()
['Class1', 'Class2', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

Nice and easy.